# Karate-Gatling: One request is not recorded

Tags: karate, gatling-plugin

One request of `rampUsers()` is not recorded.

Eg. when I do a `create.inject(rampUsers(10) during (5 seconds)).protocols(protocol)`

```
Simulation mock.CatsKarateSimulation started...

================================================================================
2019-04-22 15:59:37                                           4s elapsed
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Global                                                   (OK=9      KO=0     )
> POST /cats                                               (OK=9      KO=0     )

---- create --------------------------------------------------------------------
[##########################################################################]100%
          waiting: 0      / active: 0      / done: 10
================================================================================

Simulation mock.CatsKarateSimulation completed in 4 seconds
15:59:42.512 [GatlingSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] ERROR com.intuit.karate - http request failed: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://GatlingSystem/user/karate-68#-1547527748]] afte
r [5100 ms]. Message of type [scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration]. A typical reason for `AskTimeoutException` is that the recipient actor didn't send a reply.
Parsing log file(s)...
Parsing log file(s) done
Generating reports...

================================================================================
---- Global Information --------------------------------------------------------
> request count                                          9 (OK=9      KO=0     )
> min response time                                      6 (OK=6      KO=-     )
> max response time                                    153 (OK=153    KO=-     )
> mean response time                                    23 (OK=23     KO=-     )
> std deviation                                         46 (OK=46     KO=-     )
> response time 50th percentile                          7 (OK=7      KO=-     )
> response time 75th percentile                          8 (OK=8      KO=-     )
> response time 95th percentile                         95 (OK=95     KO=-     )
> response time 99th percentile                        141 (OK=141    KO=-     )
> mean requests/sec                                    1.8 (OK=1.8    KO=-     )
---- Response Time Distribution ------------------------------------------------
> t < 800 ms                                             9 (100%)
> 800 ms < t < 1200 ms                                   0 (  0%)
> t > 1200 ms                                            0 (  0%)
> failed                                                 0 (  0%)
================================================================================

Reports generated in 1s.
```

There should be 10 response recorded. Instead I only receive 9 responses.

Also, `atOnceUsers()` would not send the requests or generate a report. I read the issue at https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/721, and the issues might be connected.

Comment: hi - we just made some changes (see the issue you linked) and feel we have solved it, can you verify and also comment on that ticket, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, can you build from source and see if it solves the problem:

https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide

EDIT: we feel we have solved this, refer the issue you linked for details: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/721